# Update the Connection Timeout Property in all the SSIS Packages

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, msbi

We have around **600 SSIS packages** running in our production Server. We need to update the Connection timeout property of one of the **connection managers** ( We to need update connection timeout from **0 to 30 seconds**). This connection manager has been used in all the packages. I am looking a way to update this property in all the packages at `one-time`. So far I have fetched all package's XML data

```
SELECT s.name, CONVERT(XML,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), packagedata))
FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysssispackages] s
```

Need help to update only a particular property in a specific connection manager. 
 Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The above implies you're using the msdb deployment method, not SSISDB, correct? Does this also mean you aren't making use of shared data sources? This would honestly be trivial if you were, as you'd likely only have a few (at most 10-20) connection properties to change, not 100's, and you *could* do it via Powershell as well.

Comment: yes we are using msdb deployment method..not SSISDB. The connection strings are conifgured in a configuration table.